# Insert multiple rows with PDO with the same FK in one go

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to figure out how to insert new orders into my mariadb database with one query.

The PK is AI and it's called oid. If the order comes in via POST and contains only one item then parent column would be empty. If the order contains more items, then the first one would have null parent id and all following items would have it's oid FK in the parent column.

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `oid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`oid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `oid_UNIQUE` (`oid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (parent,quantity,item) VALUES (?,?,?)"; 
$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute([$lastrowid, $_POST["quantity"],$_POST["item"]]);
```

I need it to somehow group all the items belonging into the same order. Any suggestions how to insert multiple rows in PHP with one query without looping through them and at the same time implement the FK feature for cases where there is more than one item in the order.

Comment: You need to make the first insert first and then fetch the insert id to use for the other rows. The rest of the rows can be inserted in one query though (just add `VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), ...` and so on and then bind all data as well). However, since you're using prepared statements, why not just prepare the statement once first and then just execute it inside a loop with different values? That's a perfectly valid way of doing it and what prepared statements was made for.

Comment: Please provide  multi item POST example